# MongoDB map reduce find biggest sum of purchases

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a collection of purchase transactions:

```
{....,"userId": "1","amount":3,....}
{....,"userId": "1","amount":1,....}
{....,"userId": "2","amount":4,....}
{....,"userId": "1","amount":2,....}
```

I need to print userID with maximum sum of purchases and and the sum itself.

I have no problem to get sum of purchases using map reduce:

```
function map(){
    emit(this.userID,{amount:this.amount}); 
}
```

then reduce:

```
function reduce(key,value){
    var sum = 0;
    for ( var i=0; i<value.length; i++ ) {

            sum += value[i].amount;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I understand that I need to use finalize function to select the biggest result and return it as single collection.
How can I use finalize function to select the biggest result? 
Can you help?

**Update:**

In terms of SQL it should be something like this:

```
select MAX(tbl.amn), tbl.uid from 
(select o, userID as uid, SUM(o.amount) as amn from order o GROUP BY o.userID ) as tbl GROUP BY tbl.uid
```

Comment: it's a bit vague for "maximum sum of purchases", do you mean the max amount?

Comment: sorry, but i'm not so familiar with SQL statement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Output your map/reduce result into a collection.
- Build index on amount.
- Query order by amount descendingly.

Comment: Thanks. another question, Can I make such operation atomically? Because I need to make sure that another request will not overwrite output collection.

Comment: Of course you can do that automatically simply via a script. you can use [Incremental Map/Reduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-IncrementalMapreduce) to keep your output collection up-to-date, and remember ensureIndexes on the fields you care

Comment: than you for great response, I'm currently making some POC for MongoDB and Java/Spring container. I started to use incremental Map/Reduce and I se one problem, after I remove collection with specific userID from initial Orders collection and run again incrememtal MR function I still see sum of removed values. How can remove these stale values while running MR?